# Error in Django while adding a table on admin page

Tags: python, django

I'm making a simple booking app in Django. I've made a model where I'll store booking data for each day of the week and tried to add a table based on it on admin page. But when I click "save", I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: baseapp_bookingmodel) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1653, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1580, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1093, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 754, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 792, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 935, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1249, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katja\PycharmProjects\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/baseapp/bookingmodel/add/
Exception Value: no such table: baseapp_bookingmodel
```

Any ideas why this happens? Earlier I received the same error when I tried to migrate some changes in the model, but it was fixed by deleting the database and migrations and making them again. I also get the same error when I try to reference the model on pages.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/katja/PycharmProjects/django/taskmanager')


def empty_data():
    return [[0 for i in range(7)] for j in range(5)]


def empty_title():
    return 'Monday'


class BookingModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=16, default=empty_title())
    data = models.TextField(default=empty_data())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Booking'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Booking'
```

Comment: seems like forgot to migrate the database.

Answer (score 1):

You should do migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Your database has not table for this model.

Comment: I did that already and it still doesn't work. Also why does it refer to a table named baseapp_bookingmodel if I haven't specified this name anywhere? Does it write the path to model with _ by default?

Comment: And yes, I've searched for baseapp_bookingmodel in the database and haven't found anything. So there's definitely a problem with that.

Comment: I deleted the model, then added it again and migrated and it worked. Thanks!